# Confusion about class definitions

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am a little bit confused with the next terms. I thing I got it right but programmers all the time say it wrong so I want to be sure.

If we have class A and class B is inner class of class A. I hear a lot of programmers say "class A is parent of class B".
For me this is wrong. Class A is outer class of class B.
Class A would be parent class only if the class B inherits class A.

This is very confusing because (since I am Android developer) people also use this terms in defining layouts where they say:

Imageview, TextView and Edittext are children of ConstraintLayout and ConstraintLayout is their parent.
Even though I agree with this sentence it is contradictory to the previous example with classes. If we follow previous example we should say:
ConstraintLayout is outer element and these 3 are its inner elements.

Please can someone share opinion with me or confirm my doubts. Thanks

Layout example in android:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".presentation.main.MainActivity">

     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use code to illustrate the situation, rather than trying to use words.

Comment: "I hear a lot of programmers say "class A is parent of class B"" This is wrong.

Comment: Andy this is more theoretical, I really think that no code needed. Yes it is not parent it is only outer class right?

Comment: The language reference term is "enclosing class", rather than "outer class"; but I'd know what you meant if you said "outer".

Comment: I would point out that "parent class" is not an especially widely-used term in the language spec either. I believe you mean "superclass", and I suspect that colleagues would also consider these synonymous. I can only find [one usage of the term "parent class" in the JLS14 spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.5); this is meant in the sense of superclass. So, I don't know if there is a linguistic reason why the "lot of programmers" might refer to the enclosing class as the "parent"; it's not a standard usage of the term.

Comment: yes for me superclass is same as parent class. But people usually use this parent - child terminology when they have nested situations and i want to know is it wrong or right terminology.
FOR EXAMPLE - look at my layout code which I edited. My collegues would say
ConstraintLayout is parent of TextView and ProgressBarr. 
Is this right?

Comment: Indeed [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) says "The class from which the subclass is derived is called a superclass (also a base class or a parent class)."

Comment: "i want to know is it wrong or right terminology" It is wrong, if talking about classes. Parent/child refers to inheritance, not nesting.

Comment: Layouts are basically a tree structure in computer science. I've always seen parent/child terms used with trees, so therefore I think it's perfectly acceptable to use these terms when describing Android layouts.

Comment: You see guys. We already have disagreement. And I totally understand logic behind AndyTurner answer and logic behing Greg answer...

Comment: @Kratos you appear to be talking about two different things: are you asking about *classes* (and the nesting of other classes inside the code of a class), or *instances of classes* (a layout is a tree of instances; an instance of one class can contain instances of other classes)?.

Comment: I speak generally about classes. But what is difference? if class A is child of class B than instance of class A is child of class B...

Comment: A class is a kind of thing; an instance is a thing. A class is "VW Golf" or "Car transporter"; an instance is "my VW Golf", "your VW Golf", "his car transporter". You can put my car and your car onto the car transporter, but that doesn't make them children of the car transporter.

Comment: Yes for sure I know that. But I am saying that it doesn't change parent-child situation if we are talking about classes or insrtances of that classes. Instances still keep their parent-child relations

Comment: My comment down is the question that needs to be answered

Comment: in @Tewu answer

Comment: The difference is: you can put a layout element inside another layout element, and within the layout tree, those instances have a parent and child relationship; but the classes don't have a parent and child relationship, at least in the widely-understood usage of the terms, because the parent/child(/neither) relationship between classes is unchanged by however you combine instances.

Comment: Classes have parent and child relationship when the inheritance is present. Some call it superclass and subclass, some call it parent and child class.
But if I got you right you think we should call it superclass and subclass to avoid inconsistency and use parent - child terminology in difference situations like in a tree structures

Comment: @Andy can you post some answer (not important how it is written). I would like to upvote you or something since you put your time to help me understand this...

Comment: They are just terms and developer's brains are all wired a little differently. Across all the programming languages and all the decades of experience we all have, we're going to use different terms. Stick to what makes sense for you but be open to hallway discussions with a colleague who might call it something different. You don't want to be the guy who corrects everyone! :)

Comment: hahaha nice advice man. I actually agree with you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things need to be cleared up:

**In the context of *classes***: suppose you have class `A` extending class `B`. Class `A` is a *superclass* of class `B` and `B` is a *subclass* of `A`. Calling superclasses "parent classes" is much less used, but still accurate.

An inner class `B` of the outer class `A` is not a child class, as there is no hierarchical relation between those two.

**In the context of *instances***, however, the story is different. If you have a `List<List<?>>` is `List` a parent class of itself? No.

But suppose you have a

```
class Node {
    List<Node> children;

    void addChild(Node node) {
        children.add(node);
    }
}
```

```
Node a = new Node();
Node b = new Node();
a.addChild(b);
```

Now it makes sense to call `a` *the parent node* of `b`. But this example is not in class context, it's instance context.

Those are two different contexts, and one should not mangle them.

Comment: I think you are talking about *data model*, not about *instances* in general. You can model anything. In your example, you can "call `a` *the parent node* of `b`" because **you named it like that**; not because it is generally accepted terminology to call *a parent* an object that contains a list of other objects. If you were to change `List<Node> children;` to `List<Node> siblings;` then it wouldn't make sense anymore to "call `a` *the parent node* of `b`". We use the names `children` and `siblings` because it is accepted terminology in regard to tree structures, and this is what we model.

Answer (score 2):

When we have a class definition like this:

```
class A extends B {
    static class X {}
    class Y {}
}
```

Then, following standard terminology [[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html),[2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)], you can say that:

- Class `A` is a **subclass** of `B`
- Class `B` is a **superclass** of `A`
- Classes `X` and `Y` are **nested classes** of `A`
- Class `A` is **enclosing class** of `X` and `Y`
- Class `X` is **static nested class** of `A`
- Class `Y` is **inner class** of `A`

According to [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), term "parent class" is synonymous to "superclass". In practice though, it is used to mean many different things (e.g. "enclosing class", or "class of a `parent` field"). Natural language is a messy thing. People use different names to call the same thing, sometimes even when there is standard generally accepted terminology in place. So the only thing you can do, is to be aware that "parent class", depending on a context can sometimes mean "superclass", sometimes "enclosing class", and sometimes something else. If you want to be unambiguous always use term "superclass" instead of "parent class".

Comment: Yes thats how I see it also. But in tree structure in computer science we use parent - child terminology even though there is NO inheriting involved. Does it mean that we have LACK OF CONSISTENCY in naming things in programming and thats all?

Comment: When we talk about tree structure we talk about "parent node" and "child nodes". If you're asking if there is different terminology when we talk about tree strucutre in general, and when we talk about structure of a system's classes, then yes, there is a difference in terminology.

Comment: I wouldn't call it lack of consistency though. There are things that have a tree structure, that we describe using terminology specific for those things; e.g. "subordinate" and "supervisor" in organizational structure. Also structure of classes is a tree in Java, but you can make non-tree structure of classes in programming languages that support multiple inheritance (e.g. C++).

Answer (score 1):

> Imageview, TextView and Edittext are children of ConstraintLayout and ConstraintLayout is their parent. Even though I agree with this sentence it is contradictory to the previous example with classes. If we follow previous example we should say: ConstraintLayout is outer element and these 3 are its inner elements.

You are thinking that parent/child is terminology *exclusively* used when talking about classes. That is incorrect. Many programming languages don't even have classes.

What you're describing with the UI elements is more akin to a tree data structure. In a tree, there are parent and child nodes. So `ProgressBar` is a child of `ConstraintLayout` in the tree. I don't know the history behind it, but I'd bet a tree data structure was thought of before classes even existed.

In the context of Java classes, there is also a parent (superclass) or child (subclass) relationship. In this case: `class B extends A`, B is the child class, and A is the parent.

Inner classes are a completely different thing. An inner class is not a child of its enclosing class and doesn't seem relevant to this discussion. Anyone calling an inner class a child is using wrong terminology. I personally have never heard them referred to as child classes of their enclosing class.